# ProgrammingError when deploying django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an application i built that runs perfectly on local machine but once I deploy it I get a 500 server error.
The logs print this error...

```
ProgrammingError: relation "land_property" does not exist
LINE 1: ...video", "land_property"."featured_video_url" FROM "land_prop...
                 ^
```

I think it's a problem with my postgres db since my local machine runs the app just fine with sqlite.

I'm fairly new to programming and am brand new to django so your help is appreciated

Edit:
this is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
from django.conf import settings

from django.db import models
from django.urls.base import reverse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Feature(models.Model):
    detail_text = models.TextField(_('Feature Details'))


class PropertyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_random_properties(self):
        return self.order_by('?')


class Property(models.Model):
    parcel = models.TextField(_('Property Parcel'), null=True, blank=True)
    property_size = models.CharField(
        _('Property Size'), null=True, blank=True, max_length=255
    )
    contact_phone = models.CharField(
        _('Property Contact Phone'), null=True, blank=True, max_length=255
    )

    features = models.ManyToManyField(Feature)

    gallery_url = models.CharField(
        _('Property Facebook Gallery URL'), null=True, blank=True,
        max_length=255
    )
    price = models.CharField(
        _('Property Price'), null=True, blank=True, max_length=255
    )

    # Media files
    featured_image = models.FileField(blank=True)
    featured_image_url = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    featured_video = models.FileField(blank=True)
    featured_video_url = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)

    objects = PropertyManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Property {0} at {1}".format(self.id, self.parcel)

    @property
    def abs_uri(self):
        return reverse('property_detail', args=[self.pk,])

    @property
    def extra_features(self):
        return self.features.all()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.featured_image or self.featured_video:
            conn = S3Connection(
                settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET
            )
            bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_S3_BUCKET)
            k = Key(bucket)
            if self.featured_image:
                k.key = 'featured_images/{0}'.format(self.featured_image.name)
                k.set_contents_from_file(self.featured_image.file)
                k.make_public()
                self.featured_image_url = k.generate_url(
                    expires_in=0, query_auth=False
                )
                self.featured_image = ''

            if self.featured_video:
                k.key = 'featured_video/{0}'.format(self.featured_video.name)
                k.set_contents_from_file(self.featured_video.file)
                k.make_public()
                self.featured_video_url = k.generate_url(
                    expires_in=0, query_auth=False
                )
                self.featured_video = ''
        super(Property, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: did you migrated before running the project

Comment: Yes. I migrated

Comment: the problem is basically with the database where a relation was not migrated properly, do one thing, drop the database totally, then run migrate, then makemigrations, then migrate again

Comment: I've done exactly as you've said. the response was no migrations to apply. still having the same problem.

Comment: have you done something like remove a foreign key and did not migrated??

Comment: last time try one thing, go to all the migrations folder in all the apps you have remove all the files except the init.py file from the folders and then follow the steps i mentioned in the previous comment and check once

Comment: make migrations created the models but there was still no migrations to apply. same error is happening

Comment: did you deleted the migration files before migrate, makemigrations, migrate?

Comment: yes. I did exactly as you said.

Comment: can you show your models and also the code from where you think this sql is being run?

Comment: Check the database logs and share the complete error (with query). 
Also check if the user from which you are connecting to the database has required privileges to access the schema and the relation (table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I finally figured it out. my database structure looks like this...

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

Since I had the environment variables set on the server only, it was running all my migrations on the sqlite db instead. I added the environment variables to my local machine and re-ran the migrations and it worked.

Many thanks to @Exprator for all the input.

I am running into another error now though. When I try to log into django admin it says "Forbidden". Any ideas?